# How to script the java debugger command-line tool (jdb)?

Tags: java, ruby, debugging, jdb

How can I drive the debugging session with some scripting language like ruby? Is there any easier options than using [Expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) or some similar module with a scripting language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be able to use [JRuby](http://jruby.codehaus.org/) to drive your own debugger via the [JPDA](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/index.html) API.

Comment: Are you aware of any simple examples of this?

Comment: No, but: Using JPDA in Java: http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/03/java-using-jpda-to-write-debugger.html Calling Java from Ruby: http://wiki.jruby.org/wiki/Calling_Java_from_JRuby

Answer (score 3):

Check out [jdiscript](https://github.com/jfager/jdiscript); it's a thin scripting frontend for the JDI that can be used with Java, JRuby, or any other jvm language.