# Can I write scripts for JDB - the java debugger

Tags: java, debugging, scripting, jdb

I am using JDB to remote debug a program. Can I write scripts within JDB so that i can write loops and if-else conditionals to control how JDB executes and record the jdb output to a file.

My reference document for this is [GDB Scripting](http://johnnyjacob.wordpress.com/2009/07/07/gdb-scripting-short-article-for-internal-magazine/).

Comment: I cannot find any record of anyone doing this. Perhaps this answer may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/630145/1082734.

Answer (score 5):

Check out [jdiscript](https://github.com/jfager/jdiscript); it's a thin scripting frontend for the [Java Debug Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jpda/jdi/) that can be used with Java, JRuby, or any other jvm language.

Answer (score 3):

Use `expect`, for instance I use native Windows `jdb` from Cygwin `expect`:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout -1

set CP "oracle-jdbc-tz-1.0.0-RELEASE.jar;C:\\Users\\user\\.m2\\repository\\com\\oracle\\jdbc\\ojdbc6\\11.2.0.4\\ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar"

cd target
# puts [pwd]

spawn jdb -classpath $CP -sourcepath ../src/main/java
expect ">"

send "stop in home.App.main\n"
expect ">"

send "run home.App\n"
expect "Breakpoint hit:"

send "stop in home.App.run\n"
expect -re "main... "
send "cont\n"
expect -re "main... "
send "stop in home.App.barrier\n"
expect -re "main... "
send "trace go methods\n"
expect -re "main... "
send "cont\n"
expect -re "main... "
# interact
send "quit\n"
expect eof
```

To get classpath for Maven project run:

```
mvn dependency:build-classpath
```