Load JDB script for debug
O debug a JAVA  process using JDB.
I want to write a script that load into jdb script : breakpoint, print locals and set locals.
stop in ExampleClass.exampleMethod
locals 
set aaa = 123
cont

Hiw can I do that like I can do with .gdbinit?

The .gdbinit is for GDB. JDB (Java Debugger) and GDB (GNU Debugger) are two different and incompatible tools. Which one are you trying to use?

I know that gdbinit is for gdb. It just an example . I want to JDB

Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630044/how-to-script-the-java-debugger-command-line-tool-jdb
